# elastic beanstalk setting php crontab with cron.yaml

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cron-task

I've read the elastic beanstalk Periodic Tasks manual [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks),
and after looking at this code in the cron.yaml  file:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "backup-job"          # required - unique across all entries in this file
   url: "/backup"              # required - does not need to be unique
   schedule: "0 */12 * * *"    # required - does not need to be unique
```

Im not sure how to execute the following command:

```
 php /var/www/html/myfolder/task.php
```

should the url be just "/var/www/html/myfolder/task.php" or "php /var/www/html/myfolder/task.php"?

Answer (score 0):

The `url` value is what will be called by the SQS daemon on the worker instance when executing the task. In your case, the daemon will connect to `localhost` and make the following request:

```
POST /backup HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: aws-sqsd/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
...
```

as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-environ).

In other words, your script should run when executing:

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost/backup
```

from the worker instance.